# CKeditor with a url-prefix for image tags

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using CKeditor to allow users to add images to their textboxes in a CMS.

A possible scenario is this: I develop a new site for a customer at http://developer.com/customer/a. The base url is "/customer/a". But when I ship the finished site to their domain www.customer-a.com, base url is changed to "/" and all image links are broken.

I would like to CKEditor to save something like {base_url}/media/my-image.jpg, but still keep all the WYSIWYG-features of CKeditor. Is there a hook or event in CKeditor where I could replace for e g {base_url} before the html i viewed?

I would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hard way would be to use CKEditor's html parser and traverse whole html text when its loaded into editor and check/correct url of img tags.

Second option, although im not sure if it can be applied on your case, would be to make all images dependant on CKEDITOR.basePath and determine just that when CKEDITOR is initializing.

Or just develop on http://developer.com/customer/a, but let images be placed on www.customer-a.com even for development :)